# C# How to check how many numbers an Integer contains and the separate them

Tags: c#, numbers, integer, int

I want to know how I can see how many numbers an integer contains 
Example:
I have an int : 1234
Now I want these numbers back but then separated into 4 Integers

1000
 200
  30
   4

How do I do this?

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: You: 1) Figure out the problem in your head 2) Write it down on paper if necessary in English (or your native language) the steps you'd take, 3) Implement it in C#.

Comment: No It is not for homework I am learning C# myself and from internet I am making a program that converts Numbers to kanji numbers (Japanese numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo 10 to get the lowest part, then subtract that from the number and use modulo 100 to get the next, and so on:

```
int number = 1234;

for (int div = 10; number != 0; div *= 10) {
  int n = number % div;
  Console.WriteLine(n);
  number -= n;
}
```

Output:

```
4
30
200
1000
```

Comment: This fixed my problem and I also added a system that separates the numbers to a list :D thanks a lot Guffa!

Answer (score 4):

```
int num = 1234;
var s = num.ToString();

var ints = s.Select((c,i) => (int)(Math.Pow(10,s.Length-i-1)*(c - '0'))).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for perfect answer that can never be pulled off as your own homework

Comment: @ScottSelby Indeed my intension was that. But I was planning to delete it.

Comment: Sorry but its not for homework :) I do this for fun and I learn this stuff by myself and from you guys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = 1234;
int remainder = number;
int maxPow = (int)Math.Log(number, 10);
for (int factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, maxPow); factor >= 1; factor /= 10)
{
    int part = factor * (remainder / factor);
    remainder -= part;

    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

To build a collection:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetParts(int number)
{
    int remainder = number;
    int maxPow = (int)Math.Log(number, 10);
    for (int factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, maxPow); factor >= 1; factor /= 10)
    {
        int part = factor * (remainder / factor);
        remainder -= part;
        yield return part;
    }
}

Which can be used the following way:

List<int> parts = GetParts(1234).ToList();
// parts[1] --> 200
```

Note that I'm struggling not to use strings which provide a quick an dirty solutions...

Comment: can I also put these results into a list so I can call them like this : part[1] or part[2] ??

Comment: @Nobleleader13245, I've added a new source code to build a collection. You can use any linq operator on the result of GetParts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

```
 public List<int> myNums = new List<int>();

 public void getList(int Num, int Multiplier)
 {
     if (Num != 0)
     {
         myNums.Add((Num % 10)*Multiplier);
         getList(Num / 10,Multiplier* 10);
     }
 }
```

//Call

```
int N = 1234;
getList(N, 1);
```

Comment: This works, but I think is unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 1):

First, write a clear problem statement. Then decompose that into a series simpler problems. You need to

1. Decompose an integer into its component decimal digits.
2. Accumulate each of those into an array, in the correct order.

A couple of hints:

- For any integer *x*, you can get the value of the digits in the 1's position via *modulo 10* arithmetic. *123 modulo 10* evaluates to 3.
- Most computer languages that derived from the C programming language (C# being one of those) provide integer division as a default when the operands are of integral type.
- Many problems (such as this) have a general case and one or two specific or special cases. The special case here is when your starting value is zero.

In pseudocode,

- if X is zero, then return the list [0].
- otherwise...

  - create an empty list of integers called Digits.
  - while X is non-zero
  - D is X modulo 10
  - X is X divided by 10
  - append D to Digits

That will give you the list of integers...in reverse order.

Hint: There is another data structure called a `stack` that you might might find useful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing out a complete function, an easy method would be to take advantage of the fact that:

1234 % 10 = 4

Write a loop that grabs the left-most digit by computing the number modulo 10, and then divides the number by 10 (discarding the remainder) to "shift" the number right. As long as you keep track of how many times you've divided by 10, you know what position the digit you just extracted was in.

Alternatively, you can use the ToString() method found on, e.g., the Int32 class to convert the number to the string, at which point the number for each digit can be found by multiplying the digit at some string index by an appropriate power of 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<int> DecomposeInPowerOf10(int number)
    {
        if (number < 0) return null;
        if (number < 10) return new List<int> {number};

        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        char[] digits = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
        {
            int digit = digits[i] - '0';
            int value = digit * (int)(Math.Pow(10, (digits.Length - i - 1)));
            result.Add(value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```